# Process soft stack limit changes after calling occi:createenvironment

Tags: oracle, ulimit, occi

I have been using Oracle 11 `occi` libraries to interface my OracleDb server.

After trying to upgrade to the Oracle12 `occi` libraries I have noticed that the process's
soft stack size limit have chnaged.

After doing some experiments I havre zoomed in on the dfference :

On Oracle11, the `occi::createenvironment` call changes the stack size soft limit to **32MB**
(The default the process starts with is **8MB** and the hard limit is unlimited).

After moving to Oracle12 client, this behavior went away. I do ot know if this is because
of the way the client was installed or bcause of a change in the client itself.
I could ot find any documentation to this behavior.

Can you advise ?

Comment: I recall some changes in the early 11.2 or late 11.1 days that reduced the default or wouldn't let the size be changed by the app. These were fixed in late 11.2 patches and/or in 12c.   Ask Oracle Support about bug 12547243 if you want more info.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to track it down. Currently we just manually override the behavior by setting the soft limit to 32MB as was before.